# Sublime Text 3 - Hover/click events in gutter?

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

I've currently been working on a plugin that places a random coloured image on each line, based on the SVN commit number. ([Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EtrrU.png))

Now I'd like to move forward by creating a click (or hover) event from the icon in the gutter that will [open a popup](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/dev-build-3070/14538). Am I able to do this? I can't really find any documentation on gutter events, or the popups.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is an api for gutter clicks or hover events. For the popup there is some info in the [forum announcement](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/dev-build-3070)

Comment: @r-stein thanks for your answer. If you look in my question I actually linked to that post, thanks for your help though! I've also asked this same question in the forums, so if anyone finds this and was looking for more information, you'll [find it here](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/hover-click-events-in-gutter/20747)

Comment: Oh i missed that you have already linked it.

Answer (score 1):

This may be possible since Build 3124 of Sublime Text 3. Check the release notes and Sublime's Blog.

The link to the release notes of this specific build can be found [here](https://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-3-build-3124).